Adding parameters to the api in plugin based on the prompts given to semantic kernel
I am creating a plugin that calls my custom api. This custom api gets has few optional query parameters.
eg : my api can be constructed in following ways.

http://baseurl/api/employee/{id}  -- Gets emp information alone
http://baseurl/api/employee/{id}?info=address  -- Gets emp information with address
http://baseurl/api/employee/{id}?info=address&info=payment  -- Gets emp information with address and payment information

This info property is an array in my controller. And I have my plugin designed as below.
[KernelFunction, Description("Get the employee Information.")]
    public async Task<string> GetMemberInformation(
        [Description("id of the employee")] string id,
        [Description("User Query")] string userAsk
    )
    {
        try
        {
            using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync($"http://baseurl/api/employee/{id}");
            // would like to add query params based on the prompts
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return content;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           
        }

    }

I will be giving prompts like this.

Get me the employee information of 12345
NO problem for the above prompt

Get me the employee information of 12345 with address

Get me the address of employee 12345

Get me the correspondence information of employee 12345
For hte above 3 prompts, I would like to have the query param address added

Get me the complete information of the employee
For this prompt I would like to have all hte query params added.


What I would like to know is the way to call api's based on the prompts.. How can I decide on the parameters based on the prompts..  Kidnly suggest if there are any links or documentation.
Thanks..
